# Why does not gcc give me warning or error?

Tags: c++, gcc

I created shared library:

lib.h:

```
int fun( int a, int b);
```

lib.cpp:

```
#include <lib.h>

int fun ( int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Compile it:

`gcc -fPIC -c lib.cpp 
gcc -shared -o -I ./header lib.so lib.o`

My lib.h is located in ./header.
So , compilation have been successuful. After it I change lib.cpp:

```
#include <lib.h>

int fun ( int a)
{
    return a;
}
```

But nothing  occured. I wanted to see error message or maybe warning. Why is it?

Comment: You want an error or warning when exactly?

Comment: This is a feature, not a bug.  You can have functions of the same name that differ only in their parameters.

Comment: I want compiler shows me that function prototipe does not complaint its realization

Comment: @user3450947 Yes, but how would the compiler know that you want to define an implementation of that prototype (rather than an unrelated overload)?

Comment: The `-I ./header` option should be on the first `gcc` command, not the second. As for the error, I don't think that's possible; it's perfectly legal to write a function definition without a corresponding declaration (the definition itself provides a declaration/prototype).

Comment: Note that `#include <lib.h>` should be `#include "lib.h"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, it's legal to define a second function with the same name but different parameters. In C you would get an error compiling the library, but not in C++.

Now in either language, anybody who *uses* your library would get an undefined symbol error. The function listed in the header is not defined anywhere.

Comment: I know it. But I use gcc , not g++.

Comment: @user3450947 But you're compiling a .cpp file. gcc infers the language from the extension. If you want to compile as C, call the file `lib.c` or use the `-x c` option.

Comment: gcc is the driver program. It invokes either the C frontend or the C++ frontend depending on the extension on the source file (or you can specify it). `gcc foo.cpp` is nearly identical to `g++ foo.cpp`, except that the latter adds some options that you'll need if you use the C++ library.